# Creating unit test with jasmine and getting an object as my second call. How do I call the function correctly?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am very new to coding so please bear with me.
I am trying to write a test for this function:

```
redirect() {
        if (!this.userInfo || !this.userInfo.userId) {
            const originalPath = this.$location.path();
            if (originalPath === '/') {
                this.$location.path('/login');
            } else {
                this.$location.path('/login').search('redirect', originalPath);
            }
            return;
        }
```

This is my mock:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        mocks = {path: function () {return '/login';},
        search: function() {return 'redirect', 'fakepath'}};
        ctrl = new BxIndex(mocks);
    });
```

This is my test:

```
spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.returnValue(mocks);
spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'search').and.callThrough();
ctrl.redirect();
expect(ctrl.$location.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('redirect', 'fakepath');
```

It fails because the second call is an object:

```
Expected spy search to have been called with [ 'redirect', 'fakepath' ] but actual calls were [ 'redirect', Object({ path: spy on path, search: spy on search }) ].
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough info for me to get too far into it, but...  `spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.returnValue(mocks);` is saying "when ctrl.$location.path is called, return `mocks`" (which in this case is an object with `path` and `search` functions).  I'm guessing that is the part that's tripping you up.  What is `ctrl.$location.path('abc');` _supposed_ to return?

Comment: Updated question with some more original code that I am trying to test. I see that originalPath needs to be part of my test but don't know where/how to change that. I am getting that object rather than originalPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The simple answer to get around the problem with this particular test is to change this line:</del>

```
//spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.returnValue(mocks);
spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.returnValue('fakepath');
```

**Edit**: Looking at the code being tested, it looks like `ctrl.$location.path` returns different results depending on how it's called.  If it's called with no parameters, then it appears to return a string.  If it's called with a string as the parameter, then it appears to return the `ctrl.$location` object itself.  Assuming I'm correct on that, there are two options...

The first option is to just set up your `ctrl` object for the test so that `ctrl.$location.path` doesn't need to be mocked (spied) at all, if possible.

The second option is to implement the dual-return logic in your spy using `callFake`:

```
spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.callFake(function(arg) {
    if (typeof arg == "string") {
        return ctrl.$location;
    } else {
        return "fakepath";
    }
});
```

**End Edit**

But I think you're missing some details on how the `spyOn` functions work, so I will elaborate a little!

When you spy on a function, you're basically replacing that function with a spy - so if you subsequently call that function, it does nothing by default.
But you can add on to your spy too - for instance, you can have it return a specific value, or you can have it go ahead and call through to the original function that it is standing in for.  That's what's happening when you use `spyOn(...).and.returnValue()` and `spyOn(...).and.callThrough()`.

For example, let's say I have this simple object, `foo`.  It has a function called `sayHello`, which calls another function called `send`, which sends a message over the network to Bob.  If the message is sent successfully, the `messagesToBob` counter goes up by one, otherwise it remains the same.  (`send` returns true if it worked, or false if it didn't).

```
// Begin contrived example!
var foo = {
    messagesToBob: 0,
    sayHello: function() {
        if (this.send()) {
            this.messagesToBob += 1;
        }
    },
    send: function() {
        network.send("Bob", "Hello");
    }
};
```

Now I want to test this, but obviously I don't want to be sending Bob a bunch of messages during my tests.  So that's where the spy comes in.

```
spyOn(foo, "send");
```

This essentially takes the `foo.send` function and replaces it with an empty function (I believe it will just returned `undefined`).

If I want to test the `foo` increments the counter on a successful run, I can make the "send" spy return true:

```
spyOn(foo, "send").and.returnValue(true);
foo.sayHello();

expect(foo.messagesToBob).to.equal(1);
```

If I want to test that it *does not* increment on a failed send, I can make the "send" spy return false.

In any of those cases, I could also check the status of the spy function itself using the `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()` or `.toHaveNotBeenCalled()` (or whatever functions are available to your particular testing framework/environment).

Anyway, I hope that helps!  Your "mock" object's functions don't need to return a value in this example (assuming you need that object at all), because those functions are being replaced with spies anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extra information. It's making a little more sense now. How would I test that search was actually being called?

Comment: Happy to help!  The same way you were doing it originally (the last line in your original code example) should be fine.  It was just that the ‘path’ spy was returning an object instead of the string you were expecting (first code sample in this answer).  :)

Comment: I get an error saying:
`Expected a spy, but got a function`

Comment: spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'path').and.returnValue('fakepath');
ctrl.redirect();
expect(ctrl.$location.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('redirect', 'fakepath');

Comment: You still need the `spyOn(ctrl.$location, 'search');` line, otherwise ctrl.$location.search is just the original function.  :)

Comment: This works if I separate `this.$location.path('/login').search('redirect', originalPath);` in to two lines but does not work if it is the original one line. I get a different error saying **Expected spy search to have been called with [ 'redirect', 'fakepath' ] but it was never called.**

Comment: I guess I missed it before... but yeah, that's correct.  In your original code, ignoring any tests... what is `this.$location.path('/login');` supposed to return?  The issue is that we're overriding `this.$location.path` to return a string using a spy.  So when it gets called in `redirect()`, it returns a string, then calls the `.search()` method _of that string_ and not of the `ctrl` object.

Comment: Edited the beginning of the answer... hopefully that helps!